# How to Send and Receive Serialized Binary Formatter object to Http Listener

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, http, websocket

I am consuming Third Party SDK which has an implementation of HTTP Listener. The implementation is as follow:

```
private HttpListener m_httpListener;
    
public HttpListenerThd(string[] prefixes)
{
   this.m_httpListener = new HttpListener();
   foreach (string uriPrefix in prefixes)
   {
         this.m_httpListener.Prefixes.Add(uriPrefix);
   }
   this.m_httpListener.IgnoreWriteExceptions = true;
   base.CreateAndStartThread(ThreadPriority.Normal, new Thread(this.ThreadLoop));
}
    
    
private void ThreadLoop()
{
   while (!base.IsEnding)
   {
         try
         {
            IAsyncResult asyncResult = this.m_httpListener.BeginGetContext(null, null);
            bool flag = false;
            do
            {
               flag = asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(100);
            }
            while (!base.IsEnding && !flag);
            if (flag)
            {
               HttpListenerContext httpListenerContext = this.m_httpListener.EndGetContext(asyncResult);
               HttpListenerRequest request = httpListenerContext.Request;
               Stream inputStream = request.InputStream;
               Encoding contentEncoding = request.ContentEncoding;
               BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(inputStream, contentEncoding);
               StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
               MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
               bool flag2 = false;
               bool flag3 = true;
               Foo objFoo = null;
               while (true)
               {
                     byte value;
                     try
                     {
                        value = binaryReader.ReadByte();
                     }
                     catch (EndOfStreamException)
                     {
                        break;
                     }
                     if (!flag3)
                     {
                        char c = Convert.ToChar(value);
                        if (c == '|')
                        {
                           if (!flag2)
                           {
                                 flag2 = true;
                                 stringBuilder.Append(c);
                           }
                           else if (stringBuilder.ToString().StartsWith("ReportReady"))
                           {
                                 flag3 = true;
                           }
                           else
                           {
                                 stringBuilder.Append(c);
                           }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                           stringBuilder.Append(c);
                        }
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        memoryStream.WriteByte(value);
                     }
               }
               
               HttpListenerResponse response = httpListenerContext.Response;
               Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
               string empty = string.Empty;
               
                     empty = "<HTML><BODY>OK</BODY></HTML>";
                     byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(empty);
                     response.ContentLength64 = bytes.Length;
                     outputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                     outputStream.Close();
                     if (flag3)
                     {
                        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                        memoryStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        objFoo = (Foo)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
                     }
                     
               
            }
         }
         catch (Exception ex2)
         {
            
         }
   }
   this.m_httpListener.Close();
}
```

Below is the part which I am using to send request to this Third Party implementation:

```
Foo objFoo  = new Foo();
                   
MemoryStream memmoryStream = new MemoryStream();
BinaryFormatter binayformator = new BinaryFormatter();
binayformator.Serialize(memmoryStream, objFoo);

string responseString = string.Empty;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = Method;

request.ContentLength = memmoryStream.Length;

Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[memmoryStream.Length];
int count = memmoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
   
}
```

I am unable to understand that how I will be sending the request, because its checking "ReportReady" at the start of the StringBuilder. I have tried multiple ways but unable to understand that how it should work.

Comment: That's a *very* bad idea. [BinaryFormatter has unsolvable security issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) *especially* in this scenario. Microsoft strongly warns against it. The generated data is specific to that class so the service is unusable by other languages and eventually, .NET itself - the class is slowly being removed from .NET Core.

Comment: You'll have to use a different binary serialization format. [Protocol Buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/protobuf?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is very popular as it's used by gRPC and ASP.NET Core itself to build gRPC services. You can use [protobuf-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net/) or .NET Core's tooling to generate classes and serialize/deserialize objects

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I cannot use anything else as this is third party implementation.

Comment: Don't use that SDK then. This isn't 2005, the last time `BinaryFormatter` was of any use. At the very least ask the vendor to provide instructions instead of that *very* bad code. It looks like the code is trying to read a single-byte character first to set some flags, and only when `while(true)` exits does it try to read `Foo`.

Comment: Are you trying to reverse-engineer the SDK through a decompiler? Is that why the code is so bad? Is there no documentation that explains what the message format should contain, what `|` and `ReportReady` are supposed to do? You'll have to know why these are used so you can emit them before sending the `Foo` object

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I have decompiled the SDK and no documentation is available.